# Unable to access files from GCS on browser after gsutil defacl set public-read gs://[YOUR_BUCKET_NAME]

Tags: c#, google-cloud-storage

I was going through this documentation for .net project uploading files on Google Cloud Storage.

I used the command below and hoping that I can browse the file - "https://storage.cloud.google.com/tamkeen_svm/SV-000924/20170305_141619.jpg?_ga=1.228511261.1668264549.1490532014" on browser without login, but it doesn't seem to be working and shows insufficient permission

gsutil defacl set public-read gs://[YOUR_BUCKET_NAME]

Comment: I tried this url (https://storage.googleapis.com/tamkeen_svm/SV-000924/20170305_143420.jpg) now after public sharing, but it is still downloading, how will I display files images please

Answer (score 0):

Neither the bucket's ACL nor the bucket's defacl (default object acl) affect the ACL on an existing object. Try setting the object explicitly to be publicly readable:

```
gsutil acl set public-read gs://BUCKET/OBJECT
```

Read permission on the bucket itself grants users permission to list objects, and the defacl property sets the ACL that will be assigned to new objects if one isn't explicitly specified. If you set defacl to public-read and then upload a new object, I would expect that object to be publicly accessible.

Comment: What about authentication I want to do it with javascript for a object- do u mind giving me some scripts

Comment: You mean that there is a client using JavaScript, and they want to download objects using their own Google credentials?

Comment: yes, something like that I want the authentication before i see the object